# If within Switch - Case in php

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to create a query from the data i receive from an array of objects in php. I keep receiving an error on the nested if inside a case. unexpected '{', is it because I can't have an if within a case?

```
switch($name){ 
case 'players': 
      $query .= " min_players <=".$value." AND max_players >=".$value." AND"; 
      break; 
case 'max-duration':         
      if((intval($value) >= 45)  {  
          $min = intval($value)-30;  
          $query .= " duration <=".$value." AND duration >=".$min." AND"; 
      } else { //if duration < 45  
            $query .= " duration <=".$value." AND";  
      }//end else 
      break; 
}
```

Comment: Count number of `(`, then number of `)`.

Comment: It's a simple typo, I'd recommend to use an IDE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the number of brackets in a question.

Comment: fair enough. thanks peeps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
switch($name){ 
case 'players': 
      $query .= " min_players <=".$value." AND max_players >=".$value." AND"; 
      break; 
case 'max-duration':         
      if((intval($value)) >= 45)  {  
          $min = intval($value)-30;  
          $query .= " duration <=".$value." AND duration >=".$min." AND"; 
      } else { //if duration < 45  
            $query .= " duration <=".$value." AND";  
      }//end else 
      break; 
}
```

You had to add a `)` after 
`if((intval($value)`

Comment: why not remove the "(" in front of intval?

Comment: Or that - it wouldnt really matter in this case ..